# Making a pattern with java using nested loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I have to make a pattern that is of a diamond shape such as this:

```
      1
     1 2
    1 2 3
  1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 
     1 2
      1
```

I wrote this ( sorry if for the variable name, this is just a small part of my program and I'm trying to get the pattern right so I didn't mind my variables at the moment):

```
public class NewFile{

 public static void main(String []args){
   int k = 0;
   for (int i=1 ; i<=5 ; i++)
    {
     { for (int h=2 ; h >= i ; h--)
           System.out.print(" ");
      for (int j=1  ; j<= i + k ; j++)
         System.out.print(j);
      for (int w=2 ; w>= i; w--)
         System.out.print(" ");

         }
         k++;
         System.out.println();}
  }
}
```

My output is the following:

```
     1  
    123 
   12345
  1234567
 123456789
```

I realize I should divide the code into a lower and upper triangle using two loops. However, I don't know how to break the first part. I did find the "trend" but I don't see how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will display a diamond shape that is made up of asterisks:

```
 int i = 0, j, k, n;
 n = 7; // 7 characters high. Change as needed.

 for (k = 1; k <= (n + 1) / 2; k++) {
     for (i = 0; i < n - k; i++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
         System.out.print("* ");
     }
     System.out.println("");
 }

 for (k = ((n + 1) / 2); k < n; k++) {
     for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for (j = 0; j < n - k; j++) {
         System.out.print(" *");
     }
     System.out.println("");
 }
```

The integer n represents the height of the diamond in characters and can be changed as needed.

Comment: I just ran the code ( trying to figure it out haha) and I notice it only yields a flipped triangle. It does help for my second part. But I meant, how do I break the upper part of the triangle? just using the break command?

Comment: @Marc-AndreLeclair the answer is updated with code that prints a diamond of asterisks that is 7 characters high. The integer n represents the height and can be changed as needed.